# Do frequent commits improve Mercurial's ability to automatically merge?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

Is it important to commit often (fine-grained changesets) to make merges easy?

Put differently: if I do infrequent commits, will Mercurial's change record be lacking in data?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details. What "infrequently" and "easilt" means ? What kind of files ? What is the size of the commits ? How frequent are the merges ? I'm inclined to say that it won't change Mercurial ability at all, only your own ability to resolve conflicts, but it really depends on various parameters you don't provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a subtle distinction, but it isn't the size of the commits that makes merging difficult, it's how frequently you merge.  Usually those correlate strongly with each other, but not always.  For example, mercurial doesn't care if you have 100 commits between merges or 1 big commit making the exact same change.  Since you are merging from the same baseline, it effectively lumps those 100 commits together anyway.  You will have the exact same number of conflicts that must be resolved manually.

The reason people suggest frequent merges is due to human limitations, not mercurial's.  Manually solving one merge conflict a day is a lot easier for a human than solving 100 day's worth of conflicts all at once.  Also, if you do it sooner, you can often completely avoid the later conflicts.

Comment: I've read that Mercurial has an easier job of merging than, say, SVN because it has a change list which gives finer grained information about how things have been modified. But if, as you say, it lumps all of my commits together, how is accumilating a change list? Surely SVN just does, '1 big commit'...

Comment: It uses the change list to know what has changed in each individual branch being merged since the most recent version that is common to both of them.  When a line of code differs between branches, that lets it know if the line was changed in both branches, or only one.  How many commits occurred since that common ancestor is irrelevant to the equation.  All mercurial needs to know is which *branch* changed the line of code.  Subversion's problem (although they are working on it), is that it doesn't track enough information to reliably determine the correct common ancestor.

Comment: Do you think if a source control mechanism were to keep track of all the changes that have occurred in every commit it would improve its ability to automiatically merge still further? Every key press even.

Comment: Mercurial already tracks it for every commit, but it only needs that much granularity because you can potentially branch or merge between every commit. If you go longer between merges the extra detail is wasted. Likewise for every keypress.  Unless you merge between every keypress the detail is wasted. The only way to improve automatic merging further would be to somehow take the syntax of the source code into account, so you don't count something as a conflict if they are the same semantically.